# How do I import Firebase Firestore into a plain java library using Maven

Tags: android, maven, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a noob to using Maven (typically use gradle for dependencies as I'm an Android developer). I'm trying to import Firebase Firestore into my project and I've declared it in my `pom.xml` like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-firestore</artifactId>
  <version>11.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This is "resolving" in that I see it listed in external dependencies, but it's not resolving in my code.

I've listed Google's maven repository like this within the `pom.xml` as well:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>google</id>
        <name>Google</name>
        <url>https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I *was* able to import RxJava doing the same thing as I'm trying above. it resolves both in external dependencies AND in the code. What am I missing? It's probably something obvious that I just don't quite yet understand about Maven. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still figuring things out, but the issue was resolved when I added `<type>aar</type>` to the `firebase-firestore` dependency, as well as adding the `android-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

and finally, adding `<packaging>aar</packaging>` under the `<project>` tag.

I'm not sure how this all works, so comments would be awesome, but for now the dependencies are resolving just fine.